# Autocomplete regular text?

Tags: adobe-brackets

I just started using *brackets* instead of sublime text and it's great, however I am missing one thing from sublime text, which is the text autocompletion.

So for example if somewhere on the page I have the word `bird`, when I type `b` bird should appear in the popup as autocomplete.

Is this possible in *brackets*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iʼve been looking for the same and didnʼt find native option; resolved with **[brackets-wordhint](https://github.com/bigeyex/brackets-wordhint) extension**.

Comment: That'it, now it's perfect. I actually tried searching plugins myself but couldn't find this one. Also, in case you are not using it yet, make sure to install "brackets snippets".